# How to start other projects from within a project

Tags: vb.net

I have two projects A and B. I have created a third project with 2 buttons. I want to click on one button and start project A. I want to click on the other button and start project B. I imported both project A and B into the 3rd project solution explorer (including all files)

There are at least 5 of 6 articles on the internet showing what to do but none of them work for me.
I added reference to project A and project B to the 3rd project and I added Imports for both to the 3rd project.

```
Imports KeysTest
Imports Remove Columns In CSV File
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        KeyTest.Form1.Show()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Remove Columns in CSV File.Form1.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

When accessing forms from other projects, you would have to create new instances of them. The following code should work

```
Imports KeysTest
Imports RemoveColumnsinCSVFile
Public Class Form1
    Dim keytestform As New KeysTest.Form1
    Dim removeColumnsForm As New RemoveColumnsinCSVFile.Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        keytestform.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        removeColumnsForm.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What you recommended works fine. However, have I created a problem for myself by having spaces in the name of the second project, and if so, how can I rename the project without breaking it. The real project B Is several thousand lines of code.

Comment: Yes, the first project works, but the second one had red underline under the file name so I couldn't try it. I commented out the second project mouse click sub and tried the first one and it worked fine.

Comment: Please accept the answer if It solved your problem. Thanks.